# Copy data and part of row to another sheet based on date

Tags: excel, date, copy, conditional-formatting, vba

So I have an Excel workbook consisting of 2 sheets.
Sheet2 contains a lot of info

```
Column A : name
Column B : Size
...
Column P : Validity date
```

Now Validity date has conditional formatting on to filter on date.
Every date before the present day is Red
The date of today and 10 days ahead is in Orange
Every date after that is Green

[image]

In that same workbook is an empty sheet1 for reporting.
I would like to have automatically the rows that appear in red on Sheet 2 to be copied to Sheet 1 under a header "Validity date expired" and all the orange ones to appear under another header "About to expire"

[image]

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines in a macro will copy the formatting and set the value (formulas will recalculate based on the new position, so you need the value) of the original.  For this example, I copied the format and value of Sheet1:B2 into Sheet1:D4.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 4)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value
```

From here, you have to check each row's validity date value against the current date (using the Date variable in a loop.  If the date is expired, copy the row.  Keep looping until you get to a blank line.

Next, do the same thing, but check the validity date for values about to expire.